# WPF Application using MVVM Light Toolkit

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I am absolute beginner in WPF. and I am making a Simple Business Accounting Software in vs 2008 .I want to learn about mvvm light toolkit as it is easier to understand for beginners. "Which things should I refer to learn MVVM Light?"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the documentation page for MVVM Light...
http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/documentation

Look for the section Understanding MVVM and following the links to the MIX2010 video.

There is also a deep dive video from PDC 2011 http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/OPN03

Also I would advise you to try and use the latest version of visual studio and blend as the tooling has improved quite a bit since 2008.

Andy.